# Alternativa ao index.php usando .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Como faço para o `.htaccess` colocar outro arquivo, que não seja `index.php`, como primário, ou seja, colocar um arquivo chamado `home.php` e fazer ele funcionar como se fosse um `index.php`.

Também gostaria de saber algumas configurações defensivas que ele permita fazer sobre diretórios.

Comment: Rodrigo tente por um titulo mais sugestivo, "Como definir outro arquivo como primário?" por exemplo. Quanto a segunda pergunta tente ser mais especifico, assim fica amplo demais.

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo [discutida no Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2240/201).

Answer (score 6):

Para trocar o `index.php` por outro arquivo `home.php` use essa linha no seu `.htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

Mas, se quiser que todos os acessos apontem para o `home.php`, bastam 2 linhas no seu `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . home.php [L]
```

E para não listar os arquivos de um diretório, adicione no início do `.htaccess` essa linha:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda.